# Lua Script in suricata to detect the change in file

Tags: lua, suricata

I am new in lua programming. I was looking for a lua script that can read the file being downloaded through Suricata from the internet and detect if file is changed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Something like this:

```
function init(args)
    return {http.response_body = tostring(true)}
end

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
    file:close()
    return content
end

local fileContent = read_file(path-to-where-previous-file-is-stored);
local fileContent2 = read_file(init());

if fileContent != fileContent2:
     print("File changed")
```

and block if contents are same

```
drop http any any -> any any (msg:&quot;NVISO PDF file lua&quot;; flow:established,to_client; luajit:pdfcheckname.lua; classtype:policy-violation; sid:1000000; rev:1;)
```

Comment: the button you clicked to create this post is labeled "Ask Question". I don't see any question here.

Comment: Can you specify if you are using linux distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some other `open` function that is now shown in your snippet `local file = open(path, "rb")` should be replaced with `local file = io.open(path, "rb")`

`local fileContent2 = read_file(init());` will cause problems as `init()` will return a table, not a path string. This will cause an error when calling `io.open`

```
if fileContent != fileContent2:
     print("File changed")
```

is syntactically incorrect.

Replace it with

```
if fileContent != fileContent2 then
  print("File Changed")
end
```

Also a name like `file2Content` would make more sense as it is not the second content of file but the content of file 2. But that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please guide how can I get file that is being downloaded. As you said `init()` will return table.

Comment: sorry I don't know Surricata. Information like that can be found in the surricata manual. no time to read it for you sorry.